# powershell remove first characters of line

Tags: powershell, line, character

I am parsing a JBOSS log file using powershell.
A typical line would being like this :
2011-12-08 09:01:07,636 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].etc..

I want to remove all the characters from character 1 until the word ERROR. So I want to remove the date and time, the coma and the number right after it. I want my lines to begin with the word ERROR and delete everything before that.

I looked on google and tried different things I have found but I struggle and can't make it work. I tried with substring and replace but can't find how to delete all characters until the word ERROR.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This one-liner will **read the contents** of your file (in the example jboss.txt) and **replace every line containing ERROR by ERROR + whatever follows** on that line. Finally it will **save the result** in processed_jboss.txt

```
get-content jboss.txt | foreach-object {$_ -replace "^.*?(ERROR.*)",'$1'} | out-file processed_jboss.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the log line is in a variable of type string this should do it:

```
$line = "2011-12-08 09:01:07,636 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].etc.."

$ErrorIndex =  $line.indexof("Error",0)
$CleanLogLine = $Line.Substring($ErrorIndex, $line.length)
```

Reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx