# How to remove the first 3 symbols in a text file?

Tags: powershell

How to remove the first 3 symbols in a text file with PowerShell and keep the file with the same name?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [powershell remove first characters of line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8849408/powershell-remove-first-characters-of-line)

Comment: @arjabbar Your linked question is more complicated and doesn't provide an answer to his question.

Comment: It might be possible that you plain don't want the UTF8 encoding byte sequence at the start of a text file that's in reality is ANSI. If so, use `Get-Content file -encoding UTF8 | Set-Content file -encoding ascii`. Or if you need to convert to UTF without BOM, see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17699645/utf8-encoding-without-bom-powershell .

Comment: i don't want to change encoding... @MartinBrandl was right, his solution works fine

Comment: The confusion might not have existed if you showed us a file sample before and after by providing a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just read the file using the `Get-Content` cmdlet, remove the file using a *regex* that replaces the first three characters with nothing and finally write it back using the `Set-Content` cmdlet:

```
(Get-Content 'yourfilePath.txt' -raw) -replace '^...' | Set-Content 'yourfilePath.txt'
```

**Note:** You probably want to specify the *encoding* using the `-Encoding` parameter when writing the content back to the file.

Comment: Thank you! It works! Maybe you could explain, why i can't use it together with another string:
`Set-Content -Path "C:\users.txt" -Value (get-content -Path "C:\users.txt" | Select-String -Pattern 'D77B0A03BA834D938C51EBEE2E9B0250' -NotMatch)
(Get-Content "C:\users.txt" -raw) -replace '^...' | Set-Content "C:\users.txt"`

Comment: Please edit your answer and add the code as an update, I will help you

Comment: @VyacheslavMalinin  You probably missed some parentheses in this one-liner. re-check it please.

Comment: Still 2 scripts in the row are not working...  One by one everything is ok. Any ideas?
`Set-Content -Path "C:\users.txt" -Value (get-content -Path "C:\users.txt" | Select-String -Pattern 'D77B0A03BA834D938C51EBEE2E9B0250' -NotMatch) 
(Get-Content "C:\users.txt" -raw) -replace '^...' | Set-Content "C:\users.txt"`
First part of the script should remove the row with a bla-bla string, and the second part is removing 3 first symbols in the same file.

Comment: You can simplify that: `(get-content -Path "C:\users.txt" | Select-String -Pattern 'D77B0A03BA834D938C51EBEE2E9B0250' -NotMatch) -replace '^...' | Set-Content "C:\users.txt"`